# NET Core application WebMethod needs to pass in URL as parameter

Tags: webmethod

My NET Core application exposes a Webmethod.
This method needs to accept a URL as parameter for further processing.

e.g.
mysite.com/webmethod/url=https://www.google.com

It would never go through.
Instead, it shows Page Not Found.
It seems this webmethod will never be routed to my controller if there is a forward slash in the URL.

However, after getting rid of forward slash, it works very well.
mysite.com/webmethod/url=https:[www.google.com](http://www.google.com)

Could someone tell me how to deal with forward slash?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [UrlEncode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.urlencode?view=net-5.0) and [UrlDecode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.urldecode?view=net-5.0).

```cs
var queryString = UrlEncode("https://google.com"); // https%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com

var decodedString = UrlDecoce(queryString); // https://google.com
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your prompt answer. However, this won't work because it's not even routed to my controller.

Comment: @yoreciv, where are you calling the API from? Encode the string there before sending the request and then decode in the controller. If you are calling the API from a different language, there are other methods for encoding. E.g., JavaScript has [encodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)